# TabView in sheet: "Simultaneous accesses to ..., but modification requires exclusive access"

Tags: swiftui

I have a `CreateNewCard` View that is opened in a sheet. In this view I have the `KeyboardHelperView` that should be displayed if `showHelp` is true. This view contains a `TabView`. But when I run this code I get an `Simultaneous accesses to XX, but modification requires exclusive access`. The weird part now is: When I change the `TabView()` to `List` it works without any problem. Is this a SwiftUI bug? Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
struct CreateNewCard: View {
    @State var showHelp = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.blue).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("open")
                .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.spring()){
                    self.showHelp = true
                }
            }

            KeyboardHelpView(show: $showHelp)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
                .opacity(showHelp ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}


 struct KeyboardHelpView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    
    var steps = ["A", "B", "C", "D","E"]
    var images = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
            Color(.red)
            TabView() {
                ForEach(steps.indices) { index in
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                        Text(steps[index])
                        Text(images[index])
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(Animation.spring()){
                        self.show = false
                    }
                }
        }
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
        )
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay, the next weird observations: It works on a real device without any problem. And when I comment out `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))` it works on the simulator as well. I'm not sure whether this is now a Xcode/simulator bug or is this just a random behavior?!